# format macro variable to comma6

Tags: format, sas

%let vc = 12025;

ideal output (with format `comma` ) is `12,025`;

but `%put %sysfunc(put(&vc,comma6.))` seems not working. Error as below.

`ERROR: The PUT function referenced in the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not found.`

Comment: How did you create the `vc` macro variable in the first place?  Macro variables are text, so you should create it in the correct format in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `PUT` function is not available with `%SYSFUNC`, however you can use `PUTN` for numeric values, or `PUTC` for character.

Try :

```
%put %sysfunc(putn(&vc,comma6.));
```

Comment: For a complete list of functions not available with `%sysfunc()` and `%qsysfunc()` refer to the documentation: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514sysfunc.htm

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using the `putn()` function to format values returned by `%sysfunc()` is to use the little known 2nd parameter of `%sysfunc()` like so:

```
%let vc = 12025;
%put %sysfunc(sum(&vc),comma6.);
```

The second argument applies a format to the result returned by whatever function `%sysfunc()` is calling.  In the above example, I'm just summing a number by itself which effectively just returns the number.  If it was a character value, I could use the `cats()` function.

Worth noting as it will simplify code if you want to do something like:

```
%put %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(date()),date9.));
```

as it becomes:

```
%put %sysfunc(date(),date9.);
```

Comment: You need to provide a function for %sysfunc to work @randombet. The sum or cat is just a "trick" as they always return the same value as was input.